# Variables are not displayed correctly in the document

Tags: javascript

I have a question. I am doing a small exercise. I am starting. When I run the following code the **nextAge** appears in **currentAge** and I am looking for **currentAge** and **nextAge** to appear where I indicated in the **document.write**. I would appreciate it if you could correct me.

```
let yourName = prompt('What is your name?');
let currentAge = prompt('How old are you?');
let nextAge 
 
if(currentAge){
    nextAge = currentAge++;

    document.write(`Hi ${yourName}, You are ${currentAge} years old and next year you will be ${nextAge} years old`);
};
```

Comment: `nextAge = currentAge + 1`

Answer (score 4):

TLDR: you want `nextAge = currentAge + 1`

To understand this you need to understand how `++` works. When you use `++` you are simply telling the variable with `++` to increase by one. Secondly, the position of `++` in respect to the variable matters. If you have `++` leading the variable, you are saying increase variable `VARIABLE_NAME` by one FIRST and THEN do any other operations in this line. If you have `++` after the variable, you are saying do any other operations in this line FIRST and THEN increase the number by one.

So in your example

```
 nextAge = currentAge++;
```

actually translates to

```
nextAge = currentAge;
currentAge = currentAge + 1;
```

With `++` leading this

```
nextAge = ++currentAge;
```

turns into

```
currentAge = curentAge + 1;
nextAge = currentAge;
```

Comment: Good explanation!

Answer (score 1):

The `++` means increase value in the variable by 1. So what you are doing is increasing `currentAge` value and than returning that value into `nextAge`.

What you need is take value of `currentAge` and add to it 1 without changing `currentAge`:

```
nextAge = currentAge + 1;
```